Flutter - get package: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'
I am using flutter 3.22.2 and installing get package with version 4.6.5. When I build my project, it is always stuck with error log:
Error (Xcode): ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/get-4.6.5/lib/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:222:62: 
Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.

Is there a way to solve this ?
I also found related issues in this web https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/1d4xf7k/comment/l7gjt3z/ but didn't find any solution yet

try to switch it to the latest version as mentioned below :
get: ^4.6.6
https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/708203858

seems like you're using the latest futter version and the old get package version
try to switch it to the latest version as mentioned below.
get: ^5.0.0-release-candidate-6


Hi I solve it by updating get package to newest version: 4.6.6, so I can not guarantee is updating to version : 5.0.0-release-candidate-6 will also works for me

If you are not using get package directly in your pubspec, but still getting the error: check any other package which uses 'get'
by running flutter pub deps and find which package depends on get. Then update it.
You can also see it as a transitive dependency in pubspec.lock, and you can manually set a newer version, then pub get again.
